# How to profile set of process in freeBSD?

Tags: performance, process, profiling, freebsd, throughput

I am trying to debug a service with respect to its performance. The service I am trying to debug, internally spawns instances of the same binary. To improve the through-put, I am planning to increase number of instances of the binary. After a point in number of processes of the binary, through-put is not increasing. Now I am trying to reason-out why this is happening.

I need some help on where to start, tools available for process level profiling. I am using freeBSD platform.

Answer (score 1):

If using more processes doesn't improve output, then your service isn't CPU bound. It might be constrained by e.g. disk or network throughput instead.

Start with `systat`. Especially `systat -vmstat`. See `man systat`.
This will show you several aspects (like memory usage, interrupts, processot usage and disk activity) of how busy your system is.
If your program does a lot of network activity, using `systat -tcp` might give insight as well.

If your service is a HTTP server, you might want to look at [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).